# PS3 - CECHK01 - doesn’t turn on

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I turn the back power switch on, the light up front turns on and red.

When I hit the power button, light turn green then immediately turns off and nothing happens.

I have:

- Put new thermal paste on.
- Cleaned out with pressured air to remove dust and debris.
- Got a new Power Supply and replaced the old one.

All to no avail. Please help.